# Sql throwing Errors on Simple Query

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net

I am unable to execute query's with `where` clause on my database. If I remove my `where` clause I am able to retrieve data

I am using visual studio. I will display my data via images:

```
select * from dbo.Pubs
```

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tp0Bv.png)

However, when I add `where` clause it does not fetch me any data, even though value is present in the table .

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5o5zS.png)

This is how my file system for database looks:

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAmow.png)

How can i fetch my data?

Answer (score 0):

Copy word "Biosense" from table data and then put it in Where clause single quotes. There may be leading or trailing spaces with Biosense in your data.

Or Use below query:

```
Select * From dbo.Pubs Where LTRIM(RTRIM([ Organization])) = 'Biosense'
```

Also, please check whether your column name is having an extra space **before O** in **[ Organization]** or not before using above query.

Please accept if this answer helps you!